# How do I specify a policy enforcer for keycloak in a jhipster application?

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

**Jhipster** apps do not have a `keycloak.json` file even on selecting **Oauth2** authorization during creation. But the [official](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter) Keycloak documentation tells us to specify the ***policy-enforcer*** property in `keycloak.json`. Any leads on where should it be specified would be highly appreciated.

My `application.yml` file :-

```
security:
basic:
    enabled: false
oauth2:
    client:
        access-token-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token
        user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth
        client-id: web_app
        client-secret: web_app
        client-authentication-scheme: form
        scope: openid profile email
    resource:
        filter-order: 3
        user-info-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
        token-info-uri: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
        prefer-token-info: false
```

Both my keycloak.yml and app.yml files are unchanged.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The policy enforcement is [Keycloak specific](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_overview):

> Policy Enforcement Point (PEP) is a design pattern and as such you can
>   implement it in different ways. Keycloak provides all the necessary
>   means to implement PEPs for different platforms, environments, and
>   programming languages. Keycloak Authorization Services presents a
>   RESTful API, and **leverages OAuth2 authorization capabilities** for
>   fine-grained authorization using a centralized authorization server.

[image]

There's no such a feature in the Oauth2 spec. Jhipster generates your project based in Oauth2 standards and you can make a keycloak integration based on this, but cannot use its specific features. For getting it work, you'll need to use [KC specific adapters](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#java-adapters) and get rid of Jhipster's Oauth2 autoconfiguration.

Other solution might involve extending the code added by Jhipster (which I believe is based in the [Spring Security Oauth plugin](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth)) in order to extend it with this KC feature. You'll need to write sensitive code yourself, so I'd rather go the first way.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the first method and added the following lines to application.yml, but I am getting a Bad Request error with Error 400 in console log. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: keycloak:
  realm: jhipster
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:9080/auth
  resource: web_app
  credentials.secret: web_app
  policy-enforcer-config:

Comment: I get the error after entering username and password and clicking login.

Comment: Which KC adapter have you included? This might be better suited in other new question..

Comment: @XtremeBiker, Can you more elaborate about the first way?

Comment: @Hadi J jhipster generates the projects using spring Boot auth tools (based in vanilla spring security API) . What I meant here was to use keycloak spring security adapter on top of it.